# Join is not showing the right amount of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have no idea why this is not working, my first table `dbo.tsoSalesAnalysis` has 699 rows for the month of July, and all I am trying to do is **ADD** an addition column from the `dbo.[slSalesOrderTable]` with a simple join using the `custKey` as reference. However, it gives me all of the rows for the other table which is over 400,000 rows. IT SHOULD ONLY RETURN 699 ROWS + A NEW COLUMN (`CustID`)

```
SELECT 
    t.ItemKey,
    S.CustID,
    t.PostDate, t.ReturnAmt, t.ReturnsQty,
    t.SalesAmt, t.SalesQty, t.TranDate
FROM 
    [dbo].[tsoSalesAnalysis] AS t
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[slSalesOrderTable] AS s ON t.CustKey = s.CustKey 
WHERE 
    t.PostDate >= '2016-07-01' 
    AND t.CustKey = '58888'
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I don't think you understand how `JOINS` work, if you have multiple rows in `slSalesOrderTable` for each `custKey`, then you'll get those multiple rows in the result of your join

Comment: I thought Left join would solve that, but it does not. How would I fix it then?

Comment: Please post some sample data and an expected result.

Comment: `How would I fix it?`, not trying to sound rude, but the answer is "by understanding how join works". If you understand that, you'll see that if you have multiple rows per `custKey`in the second table, and you need a column from that table, then you need to define **which** row from that table you need

Comment: As @DVT mentioned, you should post sample data from each table. You will probably have to include some additional criteria on your join. For example, is there any DATE field in slSalesOrderTable that would correspond to a specific order in tsoSalesAnalysis?

Comment: @Lamak i'm sorry and yes. I was able to fix it as soon as you mentioned to create another table I just made a reference join and group it by CustId and Cust Key, which essentially just gives me one row and joining it with the other 699 rows. I'll post the answer below! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CustKey` is not unique in `tsoSalesOrdersTable`, then we'd expect more than 699 rows to be returned.

Ideally, you would have a different table, which has `CustKey` as a UNIQUE column, to lookup the value of `CustId`.  Absent that, you can get a single value out of the `tsoSalesOrdersTable` using an inline view. For example:

```
  SELECT t.ItemKey
       , S.CustID
       , t.PostDate
       , t.ReturnAmt
       , t.ReturnsQty
       , t.SalesAmt
       , t.SalesQty
       , t.TranDate
    FROM [dbo].[tsoSalesAnalysis] t
    JOIN ( -- inline view to return one row for CustKey
           SELECT ms.CustKey
                , MIN(ms.CustId) AS CustId
             FROM [dbo].[slSalesOrderTable] ms
            WHERE ms.CustKey= '58888'
            GROUP BY ms.CustKey
         ) s
      ON s.CustKey = t.CustKey 
   WHERE t.PostDate >= '2016-07-01'
```

---

If the specified value of CustKey 58888 does not appear in slSalesOrderTable, then the inline view will return zero rows. And that means the query will return zero rows, due to the inner join.

If you choose to use an outer join, then you would want to include a predicate on `t.CustKey` on the outer query as well.

Comment: Hey thanks! I fixed it right before you posted the answer LOL , but I pretty much have the same thing. Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This is very resource consuming, but your database doesn't seen big.

```
SELECT 
  t.ItemKey
  ,t.PostDate
  ,t.ReturnAmt
  ,t.ReturnsQty
  ,t.SalesAmt
  ,t.SalesQty
  ,t.TranDate
  ,(SELECT TOP 1 s.CustID FROM [dbo].[slSalesOrderTable] s WHERE t.CustKey = s.CustKey) as CUSTID
FROM [dbo].[tsoSalesAnalysis] as t
WHERE t.PostDate >= '2016-07-01' and t.CustKey= '58888'
```

Comment: this will throw an error if there's more than one row per `custKey` in the `slSalesOrderTable` (which we already know)

Comment: you can just limit it to 1

Comment: not really, since it's using `LIMIT`, which won't work with SQL Server

Comment: fine, would ROWNUM suit it better?

Comment: No, that's for Oracle

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have no other way to obtain a CustID, the solution is to simply add the [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword to the query.

Naturally it would be better if you had a customer lookup table other than the sales order table, where this wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Using DISTINCT may be prohibitively expensive. It also makes an assumption about the uniqueness of the expressions from `t`, since the DISTINCT will collapse "duplicate" rows, which may not be desirable. (btw... I didn't downvote this answer. I'm simply adding a comment here as an aid to future readers.) In some cases, adding DISTINCT is the most appropriate solution. For this case, I'd avoid DISTINCT and use a different approach.